# How is base Exception getting initialized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-2.x

I'm confused by how the following exception in Python 3 gets initialized.

```
class MyException( Exception ):

    def __init__(self,msg,foo):
        self.foo = foo

raise MyException('this is msg',123)
```

In Python 3, this outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptionTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise MyException('this is msg',123)
__main__.MyException: ('this is msg', 123)
```

How are the arguments getting initialized?  I'm surprised that the trackback shows the args since I'm not calling the super class initializer.

In Python 2, I get the following output, which makes more sense to me since the args aren't included in the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptionTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise MyException('this is msg',123)
__main__.MyException
```

Answer (score 3):

The Python `BaseException` class is special in that it has a `__new__` method that is put there specifically to handle this common case of errors.

So no, `BaseException.__init__` is not being called, but `BaseException.__new__` *is*. You can override `__new__` and ignore the arguments passed in to suppress the setting of `self.args`:

```
>>> class MyException(Exception):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
...         return super().__new__(cls)  # ignoring arguments
...     def __init__(self,msg,foo):
...         self.foo = foo
...
>>> MyException('this is msg', 123)  # no need to raise to see the result
MyException()
```

This addition is specific to Python 3 and is not present in Python 2. See [issue #1692335](https://bugs.python.org/issue1692335) for the motivations and details.